# Can array of registers can be used in tasks in verilog?

Tags: memory, task, verilog

i am trying to implement a task for a Ripple carry adder in Verilog HDL. There is an error showing:"root scope declaration is not allowed in Verilog 95/2K mode" at line no-1

```
task  rca;  `<---line 1`
input [15:0]in1,in2;
output reg [15:0]out2;
reg [15:0]c;
integer i;
begin
c=16'b0;
for(i=0;i<16;i=i+1)
begin
out2[i]=in1[i]^in2[i]^c[i];
c[i+1]=(in1[i]&in2[i])|(in2[i]&c[i])|(c[i]&in1[0]);
end
end
endtask
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare your task inside a module. I suggest to create file with `.vh` extension (Verilog Header), place you task inside this file and include your task by  `` `include `` directive. For example:

```systemverilog
module example_module(
    // list of ports
);
    `include "tasks.vh"

    // Use your task here

endmodule
```

Comment: In verilog tasks can only be defined in the scope of a module, as in the ToTamire's example. However, using \`include here can potentially cause code maintenance issues in big projects. So, using it or defining the task just directly inside a module scope is up to the project methodology.